# Efficient matricization of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, panel, dataframe

My first StackOverflow question.

So I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks sort of like this:

```
String1 String2 String3 value
word1 word2 word3 5.6
word4 word5 word6 123.4
...
```

This kind of DataFrame comes from a very long processing chain based on a huge amount of text.  (As a side note, I am getting close to memory limits and am considering HDFStores now.)

Now I would like to do linear algebra operations based on a conversion of this table into a (Sparse?)Panel or some other kind of efficient data structure that fills in the blanks with 0s.  That is, I would like to create a table whose rows are String3s and whose columns are String1 x String2 pairs, and then do linear algebra operations on the rows.  However, I would also like to be able to do the same thing with any other column -- ie, take String1 as the rows, and make columns out of String2 x String3.

I've been experimenting with Panels and pivot tables, but they don't seem to be quite right, and they often overflow the memory.

What's the right way to do this with Pandas or in Python (2.7) in general?

Edited to add this example:

The output table is going to look like this:

```
String1String2 (word1,word2) (word1,word5) (word4,word2) (word4,word5) ...
String3
word3 5.6 0 0 0 ...
word6 0 0 0 123.4 ...
```

The number of columns is basically going to be |String1| x |String2|.
Alternatively, String3 as columns and String1String2 as rows would be fine as well, since I can perform the operations on the column series.

Edited further to add the memory issue:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: A = pd.load("file.df")

In [3]: A 
Out[3]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 18506532 entries, 0 to 18506531
Columns: 4 entries, 0 to value
dtypes: float64(1), object(3)

In [4]: B = A[A[1] == 'xyz']

In [5]: C = B.pivot_table('value', [1,2], 0)
```

It crashes with MemoryError at line 160 in reshape.pyc.  This is version 0.11.0 of pandas.

Comment: can you give an example of desired output e.g. for the example you give

Comment: I edited in answer to your question, it has a table example of the output now.  I don't know if it's in good pandas output format but it should do the trick, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using pivot_table:

```
In [11]: res = df.pivot_table('value', 'String3', ['String1', 'String2'])

In [12]: res
Out[12]: 
String1  word1  word4
String2  word2  word5
String3              
word3      5.6    NaN
word6      NaN  123.4
```

This result will probably be sufficient, but if you want the blank columns, you can use itertools.product.

```
In [13]: from itertools import product

In [14]: res = res.reindex(columns=list(product(df['String1'], df['String2'])))

In [15]: res.columns.names = ['String1', 'String2']

In [16]: res
Out[16]: 
String1  word1         word4       
String2  word2  word5  word2  word5
String3                            
word3      5.6    NaN    NaN    NaN
word6      NaN    NaN    NaN  123.4
```

and to fill in the blanks with 0:

```
In [17]: res.fillna(0)
Out[17]: 
String1  word1         word4       
String2  word2  word5  word2  word5
String3                            
word3      5.6      0      0    0.0
word6      0.0      0      0  123.4
```

*Note: in 0.13 `cartesian_product` will be available in `pandas.tools.util`.*

Comment: So, I've tried this with my table, and it quickly blows up with a MemoryError on the actual pivot.  I'm only doing a subset of the table (loaded into memory) which is only 1.5M triples with values (full table is 18M triples).  I'm actually replicating an algorithm that someone else has used in another environment to do this, so I'm wondering if there's an efficient shortcut built-in or I just have to find a way to do it iteratively.

Comment: on which bit is it blowing up?

Comment: I edited the question in order to provide the ipython code context of what I'm doing.  Would it help to see the full backtrace?  It clearly hasn't exhausted my computer's full memory.  It uses up about 4GB and then fails.  Oh, and the 'xyz' subset of my DataFrame A is, as I said, 1.5M triples.

Comment: Made a typo in my example in the original question, so fixed it.  It's the same effect, though, really.

Comment: @AsadSayeed Not sure. This part (about pivot_table crashing with a memory error) might make sense as a new question or perhaps an issue on github.

Comment: I may have found a way to do this pivot table with much fewer rows in the original table.  I'll post another issue/question if that doesn't work.